# #GraphexecutionerrorinImageClassificationUsingML

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-classification

Here is my code of image classification project in machine learning, i am not able to understand this error. I have imported all the necessary libraries.

```
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint,EarlyStopping
mc=ModelCheckpoint(filepath="./best_model.h5",
                     monitor="val_accuracy",
                     verbose=1,
                     save_best_only= True)
                                                 
es=EarlyStopping(monitor="val_accuracy",
                   min_delta= 0.01,
                   patience=5,
                   verbose=1)
cb=[mc,es]
his = model.fit_generator(train_data,
                          steps_per_epoch= 7,
                          epochs= 26,
                          callbacks= cb)
```

I get the following error when I try to run it:

```
Epoch 1/26
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-d3e718f31696> in <module>()
      2                           steps_per_epoch= 7,
      3                           epochs= 26,
----> 4                           callbacks= cb)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     53     ctx.ensure_initialized()
     54     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
---> 55                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     56   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     57     if name is not None:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
      "__main__", mod_spec)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
```

and so on.. it is a very long error

Comment: You have to give more information, the complete error message, the model, the data...

Comment: Please post the **full** error trace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.